# Why can't I declare a type with both template container and template contained value?

Tags: c++, templates

Why isn't this valid C++?

```
template <typename Container, typename T>
bool
foo (const Container <T> &);
```

g++ gives me `Container is not a template` which is clearly not what it really means.

Trying `template <typename Container> template <typename T>` doesn't work either, neither does `const typename Container <T> &`

It seems reasonable to me that one would want to define an interface which is generic over both the container and the contained type.

So,

- in terms of standards, why isn't this allowed?
- in terms of designing standards, why wouldn't this be allowed, would it cause problems?
- is there a workaround in C++14, other than basing the interface on iterators?

Comment: Why can't you just use the Container and get rid of the T?

Comment: Why should it work?  You can't pass a `std::vector` you have to pass a `std::vector<some_type>`.  If you do that then you are asking the compiler to do `std::vector<some_type><T>` which is nonsense.

Comment: Thing is, you're telling your compiler that your 2 generic parameters are types although Container is not a type as long as it is not given its own generic parameter.

Comment: A workaround different than SergeyA's answer (which I upvoted) is to just template on Container and derive T either as Container::value_type, or decltype(*begin(container)) if you don't want to assume value_type is present.

Comment: @StefanAtev which is also better because it doesn't assume that the container is a template or that it has all type template parameters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this:

```
template <template <class... > class Container, class T>
bool foo (const Container<T> &);
```

This syntax (`class...`) tells the compiler that `container` is a template with any number of arguments.

Remember, when you have `template <class T>` you want T to be the type. `std::vector` is not a type, it is a template. `std::vector<int>` is a type, but that is not a template, so you can't have `std::vector<int> <char>`.

Comment: You could use `template <class...> class container`, which would work for `std::vector`.

Comment: @TartanLlama, yes, certainly. Edited.